# Angular + JQuery - Angular Code inside Jquery Append() Function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Guys I am new to Angular, we are using jQuery for our Application but now we want to introduce Angular in some parts. So, we have jQuery.append() which is used to manipulate DOM, now I want to insert Angular code there. So, when I am inserting using .append() the code is not working.

```
<div id='Overview' name="Overview" class="inner"></div>
```

And something like this,

```
 $(document)
    .ready(
            function() {
              $("#Overview").append("<div ng-controller='jQueryController'><span ng-bind='title'></span>");
             });
```

I read that i need to use **$compile**, but not getting how to use it. Also, will it be ok to use like this and will not have any performance issues?

Comment: Hooboy. Perhaps if you expounded on your project a bit we could suggest an alternative approach. This seems like you're trying to use AngularJS just for the sake of itself and holding it on with duct tape. :P

Comment: Please, please, please, don't mix Angular & Jquery up. It's a recipe for bugs. You need to make a choice, either - or.

Comment: @OmriAharon..y?? wht bugs? its a legacy code so i cannot go and modify complete jQuery...so i have appended the angular code inside jQuery and bootstrapping angular manually.